# Box API v2 - Retrieving folder items with fields, is tag allowed?

Tags: box-api

I'd like to move up to v2 of the Box API, however I cannot currently retrieve the tags like you can in the previous api. Can you add the tags as a field in the GET call to the v2 api?

Thanks all,

Chad.

Comment: The v2 API documentation doesn't mention anything about tags -- as far as I can tell there's no way to add them to a file/folder.  I wonder if they might be deprecated?

Comment: I sure hope not, we use those pretty heavily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are a part of the V2 API.  If you look at the [documentation for folders](https://developers.box.com/docs/#folders), you can see that the tag entry is a green entry.  That means that you have to explicitly ask for that field in order for us to return it to you.  The [?fields paramete](https://developers.box.com/docs/#fields)r will let you ask for only the fields you want (instead of the default set that Box automatically gives you as part of it's responses)

Note that if you are trying to get this info for all the items in a folder, there is a difference in asking for the details about a folder, and asking for the details about every item in a folder.  ?fields works for both (and also works if you're doing a POST or PUT operation too).

If you want the details about a *single* folder:  `GET ./folders/<id>?fields=a,b,c`

If you want the details about all the items *inside* a folder `GET ./folders/<id>/items?fields=a,b,c`

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Can we get an update on this? I wanted to do a both-way sync of tags, but that does not seem possible at this moment. When will you be releasing the appropriate API to interact with documents tags?

Comment: I'm really interested in getting tags from files also.

Comment: Is there any update on this, we are getting closer and closer to the end of V1's life and I'll need to know asap the status of this.