# Box API v2 - Retrieving tags for folders and files

Tags: box-api

This seems like a bit of a duplicate posting but I didn't really know what the best way to follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033034/box-api-v2-retrieving-folder-items-with-fields-is-tag-allowed) post was.

I'm definitely interested in being able to retrieve tags that are associated with the various files and folders and I'd like to do it without having to implement that all using a version of the API that is going to be deprecated this year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Box API v2 - Retrieving folder items with fields, is tag allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033034/box-api-v2-retrieving-folder-items-with-fields-is-tag-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for following up. Tags are definitely still planned for the V2 API and we will be adding them relatively soon.